# Do you know a framework that handle a web base whiteboard?

Tags: java, .net, php, frameworks

I'm looking after a framework that offers the standard management of a whiteboard. ie a zone where the web user can draw something with his mouse and will be saved to the server when the form is posted (for instance). (Php, java, .net ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://cristian.nexcess.net/ajax/whiteboard/